# How to create one dataframe from multiple csv files in a folder

Tags: python, r, dataframe, concatenation

I have a list of CSV files(A1.csv, A2.csv........D10.csv) in a folder which contains data two columns but several rows. Basically, I want to extract the values of last row and 2nd column from all the csv files
[See the picture to understand better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bexLU.png)

and create a data frame which will contain file name in 1st column and the extracted values(C) in the second column.

Now, I can do it by creating another list of CSV files and concatenate them later into one data frame.

Is it possible to store each data frame produced by CSV files into a list and then concatenate them (what rbind do in R). I tried this code in R, it works. But I want to learn the more efficient way in R or python.( Python is preferable as I am trying to learn python)

```
#read through csv files and select the last row 2nd column
m=c(NULL)
aa=c(NULL)
f=list.files(path = getwd(),pattern = '.*csv')
for (g in f){
aa=read.csv(g)
m=tail(aa,1)
q=m[,2]
yy=data.frame(ID=g,Final=q)
write.csv(yy,file = paste("Filename/",g),row.names = F)
}
###concatanate into one file
readFile=list.files(path = getwd(),pattern = "*.csv")
Alldata=lapply(readFile,function(filename){
dummy=read.csv(filename)
return(dummy)
})
FinalFIle=do.call(rbind,Alldata)
write.csv(FinalFIle,file = "FinalFIle.csv",row.names = F)
```

Comment: What have *you* tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: Now you can see my code in the post

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option in R.

Step 1: Prepare a vector with file names. If there are too many files in the folder, the `list.files` function could be useful. Here, I just manually created it. I also assume that all the files are stored in the working directory. Otherwise, you will need to construct the file path.

```
file_vec <- c("A1.csv", "A2.csv", "A3.csv")
```

Step 2: Read all CSV file based on file_vec. The key is to use the `lapply` function to apply `read.csv` of every element in `file_vec`.

```
dt_list <- lapply(file_vec, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Step 3: Prepare a vector showing file names without `.csv`

```
name_vec <- sub(".csv", "", file_vec)
```

Step 4: Create the data frame. `x[nrow(x), 2]` is a way to access the last value of the second column.

```
dt_final <- data.frame(File = name_vec,
                       Value = sapply(dt_list, function(x) x[nrow(x), 2]),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

`dt_final` is the final output.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking something like this

Comment: I am glad to help. Please accept my answer if this post is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another option using the `tidyverse` in R:

```
library(tidyverse)

# In my example, I'm using a folder with 4 Chicago Crime Datasets
setwd("INSERT/PATH/HERE")

files <- list.files()

tibble(files) %>%
  mutate(file_contents = map(files, ~ read_csv(file.path(.), n_max = 10))) %>% 
  unnest(file_contents) %>%
  group_by(files) %>%
  slice(n()) %>% 
  select(1:2)
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   filename [4]
                         filename    X1
                            <chr> <int>
1 Chicago_Crimes_2001_to_2004.csv  4904
2 Chicago_Crimes_2005_to_2007.csv    10
3 Chicago_Crimes_2008_to_2011.csv  5867
4 Chicago_Crimes_2012_to_2017.csv  1891
```

Note that the `n_max = 10` argument isn't needed. I only included this because the files I was working with are pretty large.

For anyone interested, the dataset can be found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/currie32/crimes-in-chicago/data).

Also, it's possible that you may want to avoid setting the work directory with `setwd()`. If this is the case, you can use the additional argument `full.names = TRUE` in `list.files()`:

```
path <- "INSERT/PATH/HERE"
files <- list.files(path, full.names = TRUE)
```

I'd recommend this approach as scripts containing the line `setwd()` aren't flexible, paths will change from user to user.

Answer (score 2):

Python Solution

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> files = ['A1.csv', 'A2.csv', ... , 'D10.csv']
>>> df_final = pd.Dataframe({fname: pd.read_csv(fname).iat[-1, 1] for fname in files})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy case for `bash` and friends. This one-liner

```
for i in A*.csv B*.csv C*.csv D*.csv; do awk -F , 'END{ print $NF }' "$i"; done
```

extracts the bottom right field, no matter how many rows or columns, of any number of files that follow the pattern you have given. If all files were in one in one folder, and they were the only `.csv` files in that folder, and you wanted to save the outcome in a new file, this would do the job:

```
for i in *.csv; do awk -F , 'END{ print $NF }' "$i"; done > extract.txt
```