# read.csv.folder - quickly pulling pieces of data from one folder

Tags: r, merge, mapping, read.csv

I am currently trying to merge two data files using the map_df code. I have downloaded my dataset [https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/baby-names-from-social-security-card-applications-national-level-data] and placed it within my working directory's file location. It is a file with many separate smaller files. I am hoping to import the dataset quickly using map_df instead of having to name every single file in code. However, when I try to pull the data from that folder:

```
namedata.df <- read.csv.folder(Namedata, x = TRUE, y = TRUE, header = TRUE, dec = ".", sep = ";", pattern = "csv", addSpec = NULL, back = TRUE)
```

I get a return of:     Error in substr(folder, start = nchar(folder), stop = nchar(folder)) : 
  object 'Namedata' not found

Why might it be missing the folder? Is there a better way to pull in a folder of data?

Comment: The way I typically do this is by using `list.files()` to get a list of the file names, and then using `lapply()` (or another apply function) to call `read.csv()`. Pseudo code: `lapply(filenames, read.csv, ...)`

Comment: @Mako212 +1 for `list.files()`, though a trap for young players is that the `full.names` parameter is `FALSE` by default. Set this to `TRUE` to get the full path and filename so `read_csv()` can find the file.

Comment: @Snubian I was confused for a moment because I've never had an issue not changing that argument, but I guess that's relevant if you run `list.files()` on something other than your working directory. I typically `setwd()` to the relevant folder, avoiding that issue.

Comment: Please see my answer and others [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47492814/7362046). As other said, using a combination of `list.files()` and `map` will get you there. Note, the question is slightly different as the user wants the last row of each data frame but you could easily modify the code by removing the last couple lines in the chain (i.e. stop at `unnest()`).

Answer (score 0):

Try projectTemplate. When you run load.project() command it loads all csv, xls files as dataframes. The data frame names are same as the file names